# Extract content between first one match and first different match across one or multiple lines

Tags: line

Let's say I want to get the text between the first match of "start_" and the first of "_end", no matter it it's across same or multiple lines. Don't include the matches.

Example text 1:

```
This is a start_text with start_and some_end text with_end
```

out text 1:

```
text with start_and some
```

Example text 2:

```
This is a
start_text with
start_and some_end
text with_end
```

out text 2:

```
text with
start_and some
```

I've seen lots of answer but they are line-focused, not file-focused. Any kind of tool or command will do as long as it's console-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -l -0777ne 'print $1 while /start_(.*?)_end/gs' your-example-2
text with
start_and some
```

- `perl -n` is the `sed -n` mode where the supplied `e`xpression is run for each *line* of the input like in `sed`.
- `-l` is for a new`l`ine to be automatically appended when `print`ing¹
- `-<octal-number>` sets the record separator to be the byte  with the given value instead of newline. `0777` (511) or anything above 0377 (255) is a byte value that cannot exist, so there will be one any only one record: the whole file.
- `*?` like `*` matches 0 or more of the preceding atom (here `.` which matches any single character), but while `*` would match as many as possible, `*?` matches as few as possible, so that `.*?` will run until the first occurrence of `_end`, not the last.
- the `s` flag to the `/regexp/` pattern matching operator is needed for `.` to also match on newline characters, which it doesn't by default.

You should be able to use `pcregrep` as well, however I find (with Debian's version 8.39 2016-06-14) that it gives:

```
$ pcregrep -Mo1 '(?s)start_(.*?)_end' your-example-2
text with
start_and some
and some
```

Which I can't explain. `pcre2grep` (version 10.42 2022-12-11) is OK though:

```
$ pcre2grep -Mo1 '(?s)start_(.*?)_end' your-example-2
text with
start_and some
```

---

<sup>¹ Technically, it causes the record separator to be stripped from the input before storing in `$_` *and* the output record separator (`$\`) to be set as the same as the input record separator (`$/`) which at that point is still newline, so it's important that that `-l` come before the `-0...`. Beware that `-l<octal>` sets the output record separator to the given byte value, so it's different from `-l -<octal>`.</sup>

Comment: That works perfectly thanks!

Comment: `pcregrep version 8.45 2021-06-15` gives the correct output the same as perl.

Comment: @Smeterlink, thanks for checking. I'm not too sure what the exact status of the old PCRE (which Debian calls pcre3) is on Debian, but in any case [that old PCRE is discontinued](https://lists.exim.org/lurker/message/20210615.162400.c16ff8a3.en.html) and we should all be switching to PCRE2.

Comment: `pcre2grep version 10.42 2022-12-11` also confirming that works fine like perl, the latest versions of both have the bugs fixed.